# ". . . 30 more" in Eclipse LogCat. How to show those 30 more?

Tags: java, eclipse

The title actually says it all. I tried double clicking, right clicking and swiping that line. I even tried standing on my head, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know how I can view the extra messages that Eclipse so "conveniently" hides from me?

Comment: I doubt you'll be needing them anyway since the major line of code that caused the error is posted before the "...30 more".

Comment: You can increase the number of errors you see in Preferences>Java>Compiler>Building>Max no. of problems 100 there increase it.